# Expo error: element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I built a basic app with the Expo framework that just has a login page, a custom font, and custom styling. The painful thing is that I cannot find which file is triggering this error. I'm getting this error and I have no idea where it's being triggered or why it's being triggered. Here is the repository for it: https://github.com/amicharski/react-native-is-annoying-sometimes

I triple checked it with other developers to make sure I'm not going insane and all of my imports seem to be working fine, but I still get this error:

```
LOG  false
 LOG  true
 ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in 
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 LOG  true
 ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in 
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
 ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

My environment:

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
Binaries:
Node: 18.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 9.5.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
npmPackages:
expo: ~48.0.18 => 48.0.19
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.71.8 => 0.71.8
Expo Workflow: managed
```

I checked the versions of my packages to make sure that they're correct and in fact Expo 48 is compatible with React 18.2 which is also compatible with React Native 0.71.8.

Comment: in your LoginPage.js you need to import Text , View , TextInput and others you have to import from 'react-native' check your other files import too.